# How to Crop Images without using Intent in Android

Tags: android

I am trying to crop an image I have used the code below

> Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
>                   i.putExtra("crop", "true");
>                   startActivityForResult(i, 1);

But i have to do crop image without using Intent. And also have to customize the croping UI.
please help me out how to do that.

I am not supposed to use `new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");`
with Thanks
Vikash

Comment: no idea about your query , but nice to know i.putExtra("crop", "true");

Answer (score 8):

Here is a sample project that Works same like Default Crop Intent of Android.
**[CropImage](https://github.com/biokys/cropimage)**
If you really looking to try what you said,First look in to this link,Hope it may help you to find your way.

Comment: the link to the code you have given is not working. but i got some idea about CropImage.java class.  Thanks

Comment: ya i have installed the project but after taking picture from android camera then press ok button it is giving Force Close. I am getting into the code, if i have any problem i will get back to you. Thanks

Comment: strange..cause the same works fine in all my devices thats why i told you so confidently..anyways,,,you can send me logcats for the errors and i will try to help if i could..In that take the whole package to your project call CropImage.java with passing your bitmap and get that bitmap in cropimage.java and replace necessary

Comment: this is the errer in Logcat11-16 14:02:52.155: VERBOSE/camera(349): mJpegCallbackFinishTime = 6ms
11-16 14:02:56.125: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(340): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-16 14:02:56.125: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(340): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.droid4you.util.cropimage/com.droid4you.util.cropimage.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.droid4you.util.cropimage/com.droid4you.util.cropimage.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: where you are testing this? if it's 2.1 change it to higher or lower any..and if possible test in device..this error i seen while taking photo and intent failed sometime with passing extra parameters to it.

Comment: without this inbilt apps it`s possible to crop the image

Comment: @ZalaJanaksinh bapu, are you asking a question or telling it?

Comment: Dear i asking question.it`s possible i want to do this and my code is here if have any idea please help me.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11840811/how-to-get-select-area-which-cover-by-canvas-in-android  thank in  advance dear

Comment: This code needs to be modified a little, because the newest Camera application does not seem to work with being supplied a file path to save the captured image, instead it returns a content URI which needs to be read out of instead of trying to open a file. Other than that, it's a great library and works wonders.

Comment: @Vikash Kumar I met the same problem and solved it by changing the code of MainActivity. The problem was found on SAMSUNG devices, both 2.2 and 4.1. Here is my solution: add the following code to the end of the onCreate function: mImageCaptureUri = Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/temp.jpg"), and delete the initialization code for mImageCaptureUri in the doTakePhotoAction function.

Comment: Find the reason finally. Because the SAMSUNG phone destroy the MainActivity and create it again when returning from the Take Picture Activity, the mImageCaptureUri is null, leads to the NullPointerException. Some phones won't destroy MainActivity when returning, so the mImageCaptureUri has its value and the program works well.

Comment: @Leoguo I think you have worked enough on this topic, guess more than my self, So I suggest you to take some time and write a complete good answer and post it below as another answer, that will help us all in a better way..good work.. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [createBitmap()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) to extract a subset of a current bitmap.

Answer (score 1):

take a look at the following link. Should provide a good stepping stone to step up a ui with pinch to zoom and scroll and finally once you have what you want you can use a second view as your crop region. depends on what your looking for otherwise createBitmap option also works.
http://blog.sephiroth.it/2011/04/04/imageview-zoom-and-scroll/

```
 View view = findViewById(R.id.crop_region);
 view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
 view.buildDrawingCache();
 Bitmap cropBitmap = view.getDrawingCache();
```

Comment: this link is for touch zoom and scroll behavior.

Comment: am aware but i was assuming you would be allowing your users select the area they want to crop by using some form of bounding box. which is why i provided that and the above code which creates a bitmap of all the content within a bounding frame/view.