# how to get select area which cover by canvas in android

Tags: android, canvas

hi i want create simple cropImage Apps.so I Use `canvas` and draw it rubtime.i draw the canvas over the view.so i want get clip the area which cover by canvas.
so here i do like this.

First Create `Canvas Example`

```
public class CanvasExample extends Activity 
    {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */

        RelativeLayout relMainOperationLayout;
        RelativeLayout relTabHeader;
        RelativeLayout relMidalLayout;
        RelativeLayout relBelowLayout;
        Context myContext;
        DrawCanvas drawCanvas;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            myContext=CanvasExample.this;

            LayoutInflater layoutInflater=(LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);   

            int layoutId = myContext.getResources().getIdentifier("main","layout",getPackageName());

            relMainOperationLayout = (RelativeLayout) layoutInflater.inflate(layoutId,null);

            relTabHeader=(RelativeLayout) relMainOperationLayout.findViewById(R.id.relHeadLayout);

            relMidalLayout=(RelativeLayout) relMainOperationLayout.findViewById(R.id.relmidalLayout);

            relBelowLayout=(RelativeLayout) relMainOperationLayout.findViewById(R.id.relBelowLayout);

            drawCanvas=new DrawCanvas(CanvasExample.this,myContext);
            //drawCanvas.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
            drawCanvas.setBackgroundDrawable(CanvasExample.this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams drawParams=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,200);
            drawParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, relTabHeader.getId());
            //relMidalLayout.addView(drawCanvas,drawParams);
            relMainOperationLayout.addView(drawCanvas,drawParams);
            setContentView(relMainOperationLayout);
        }
```

after this i create one class `DrawCanvas` extends `View`.
and Draw the `Canvas` run time.

```
public class DrawCanvas extends View 

{

Context drawContext;
Activity drawActivity;
ImageView image;
Paint mPaint;
int left=0,right=0,top=0,bottom=0;
Canvas passCanvas;


public DrawCanvas(Activity activity,Context context)
{
    super(activity);
    this.drawActivity=activity;
    this.drawContext=context;


        mPaint = new Paint();

        mPaint.setDither(true);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(3);

    this.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        //@Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
        {

            switch (event.getActionMasked()) 
            {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                invalidate();
                left=(int) event.getX();
                right=left+1;
        top=(int) event.getY();

                bottom=top+1;               

                mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
           onDraw(passCanvas=new Canvas());
            break;
            case   MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:                 
                invalidate();

                int tempX=(int) event.getX();

                if(tempX>right)
                {
                    right=right+1;

                }else
                {
                    right=right-1;
                }                   
                int tempY=(int) event.getY();

                if(tempY>bottom)
                {
                bottom=bottom+1;                
                }else
                {
                    bottom=bottom-1;        

                }
        mPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                onDraw(passCanvas=new Canvas());
            break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                invalidate();
                mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
                onDraw(passCanvas=new Canvas());
                System.err.println("After Touch Up");
                Rect rect= passCanvas.getClipBounds();
                System.err.println("Save Canvas-->"+passCanvas.save());
                System.err.println("Display Rect Width==>"+rect.toString());

            break;
            default:
                break;
            }
    return true;
        }
    });     

}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
{

    canvas.drawRect(left, top, right, bottom, mPaint);

}
```

}

so now i what to do i want crop the covered area by canvas.
Thank in advance.

when  i getClipBounds it Display null value now i what to Do.

Comment: calling onDraw(passCanvas=new Canvas()); from onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) will not change the UI, you have to call invalidate(); then android will call the onDraw in next ui cycle.

Comment: i do all the thing.my question is how to get the area which cover by Canvas

Comment: getWidth(), getHeight() will give you the widht and height of view.

Comment: i do this but it`s doesn`t help me. any another way to select and crop image in android 2.2

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do non rectangular cropping. Please refer to [Android - Crop an image from multipoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11579645/android-crop-an-image-from-multipoints/11841619#11841619) or [How to crop an image in between four points on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17721111/how-to-crop-an-image-in-between-four-points-on-android)

You might find them useful.

Best of Coding!